# Prove that $IntCl(A)$ is regular open

Tags: general-topology

A set $A$ is said to be regular open if $IntCl(A)=A$

I am trying to prove that $IntCl(A)$ is regular open for any $A\subseteq X$

One of the inclusions is direct,

$Int(Cl(A))\subseteq Int(Cl(Int(Cl(A))))$

I have problems proving the inverse inclusion.

Comment: Hint: $\operatorname{int}(\operatorname{cl}(A)) \subseteq \operatorname{cl}(A)$, and both $\operatorname{int}$ and $\operatorname{cl}$ are increasing.

Answer (score 0):

As Daniel Schepler marked, $Int(Cl(A))\subseteq Cl(A)$. This is due to the fact that $Int(A)\subseteq A\subseteq Cl(A)$. So, if we substitute $Cl(A)$ by $A$, $$Int(Cl(A))\subseteq Cl(A)\subseteq Cl(Cl(A))=Cl(A)$$ As a consequence,$$Int(Cl(Int(Cl(A))))\subseteq Int(Cl(Cl(A)))=Int(Cl(A)),$$ as you wanted to prove.

Comment: @DanielSchepler If $F$ is closed then $F = \operatorname{cl}(F)$. No need for a "similar" proof, rather an identical proof.

Answer (score 0):

$$Int(Cl(A))=Int(Int(Cl(A)))\subseteq Int(Cl(Int(Cl(A))))\subseteq Int(Cl(Cl(A)))=Int(Cl(A))$$

Comment: Could you comment a bit more your answer?

Comment: Whag don't you understand about it?

Comment: I can understand, but maybe another reader can not. Which is the property that you used here?

Comment: What reader doesn't understand what?